# How to set a timeout on WMI queries?

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, wmi

I have a .NET application which runs WMI queries on all domain computers in order to find the logged in user; it pings each computer to find whether it is online or not, then runs the actual query.

Code snippet:

```
try
{
    string loggedonuser = null;

    string computername = "ComputerToQuery";

    ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();

    co.Username = "DOMAIN\MyUser";
    co.Password = "MyPassword";

    co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;

    ManagementPath mp = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + computername + @"\root\cimv2");

    ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(mp,co);

    ms.Connect();

    ObjectQuery oq = new ObjectQuery("SELECT username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms,oq);

    foreach(ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        loggedonuser = (String) mo["username"];
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Handle WMI exception
}
```

The problem: sometimes the WMI query hangs on indefinitely.

How can I set a timeout on it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ManagementObjectSearcher has an [`Options`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.options.aspx) property: one of the available options is [`Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementoptions.timeout.aspx), of type `TimeSpan`:

> Gets or sets the time-out to apply to
>   the operation. Note that for
>   operations that return collections,
>   this time-out applies to the
>   enumeration through the resulting
>   collection, not the operation itself
>   (the ReturnImmediately property is
>   used for the latter). This property is
>   used to indicate that the operation
>   should be performed
>   semi-synchronously.

Comment: Is it possible to do in C++?

Comment: @Mayur If you're using C++/CLI then yes. If not, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 6):

Try `co.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);`

Comment: This is only for the connection, not for the actual query; useful anyway, should the connection take too much time (firewalls, etc.); but in my case it's the *query* that is hanging.