# Timeout on Python WMI queries?

Tags: python, wmi

I am doing bulk information collection on hundreds to thousands of computers. Its working on 99% of the machines I'm trying, however some computers act really strange.

There is one machine (Windows XP) where I can connect successfully but it completely locks when I do a query. I stopped waiting after 15 minutes.

My code:

```
log.info("Connecting to " + remote_name + " WMI")
remote_connection = wmi.connect_server(server=remote_name,security_flags=0x80,impersonation_level="Impersonate")
log.info("Linking to WMI remote")
remote_wmi = wmi.WMI(wmi=remote_connection)
log.info("Connected")

log.debug("Getting workstation type")
for s in remote_wmi.Win32_ComputerSystem():
    self.logger.debug("Past the query!")
    compInfo["Workstation make"] = s.Manufacturer.strip()
```

In the log I get

```
12:21:12 PM [dump-COMPNAME] INFO - Connecting to COMPNAME WMI
12:21:16 PM [dump-COMPNAME] INFO - Linking to WMI remote
12:21:16 PM [dump-COMPNAME] INFO - Connected
12:21:16 PM [dump-COMPNAME] DEBUG - Getting workstation type
```

Never makes it to "Past the query!". No exception is thrown. Its just stuck.

How can I have the query timeout after 60 seconds instead of permanently freezing? Is ther an alternative?

The only thing I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355616/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-wmi-queries), but its for C#